I can't wget on my public address from within my docker instance
I run a docker + traefik infra to host several appliances. My issue is that I can't wget (or curl) on my public address from any container but the traefik one.
For example, I'd like to wget my https://auth.mydomain.name from my container that provides https://nextcloud.mydomain.name to implement a SSO.
I can ping, put the access to the port 80 or 443 does not work.
I tried from the traefik container, and there it works.
I manage others similar deployments that are working well.
Any idea about what can be happening ?

OK, found it.
It was due to the docker daemon "userland-proxy" I enabled a few days ago.
